# iOS - AVFoundation - Is it possible to set an entire video as slow motion?

Tags: ios, video, avfoundation

I'm currently able to create a composition using slow motion video as captured on an iPhone 5s, but the range and duration of the portion of the video that is in slow motion is entirely dependent upon whatever the user has specified when editing the video (or, if they haven't edited the video, the default slow motion range that seems to ramp up 3 seconds after the video commences and ramp down 3 seconds before the video ends).

Is it possible to ignore this inconsistency and simply make the *entire* video slow-motion? Or indeed, make the entire video play at normal speed?

Answer (score -1):

If you would like to play the video in slow motion, you can use setrate property. as default value is 1.0, you can set this value 0.1 to 1.0 for slow rate. and 1.0 to 2.0 for faster play rate.
Thanks

And if you would like to save it permanently.
You can create a video composition track and use scaleTimeRange method to set play rate.